# Bounded Borel functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

> Can a bounded Borel function $f$ on a compact set $K$of $\mathbb{C}$, be approximated pointwise by a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous function on that compact set? If so can we say that a property of such continuous functions related to integration, also holds for $f$? I mean for instance if $\int_K f_n(z) dz=a$ for all $n$, then is it true that $\int_K f(z)dz=a$?

I know that the convergence cannot be uniform, because if it is uniform, then $f$ is also continuous, but $f$ is not necessarily continuous(e.g.: Characteristic function on a Borel set). So how do we know that the integral property holds if the convergence is pointwise? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with a.e. pointwise convergence by Lusin's theorem.

Comment: Ok but how do we take the limit under integral sign?

Comment: A function that can be approximate pointwise by a sequence of continuous functions is called "Baire class 1".  Not all Borel functions are Baire class 1.  There is a transfinite hierarchy of Baire classes; the Borel functions are in some sense those which are Baire class $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence $f_n$ of continuous functions. 
Note that $f(x) \le y$ if and only if for all positive integers $m, k$ there is some $n \ge k$ such that $f_n(x) < y + 1/m$, i.e.

$$ \{x: f(x) \le y \} = \bigcap_{m,k \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{n \in k + \mathbb N} \{x: f_n(x) < y + 1/m\} $$

Thus $\{x: f(x) \le y\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$, i.e. intersection of countably many open sets.  Similarly, $\{x: f(x) \ge y\}$ is a $G_\delta$, so $\{x: f(x) \le y\}$ is an $F_\sigma$, i.e. union of countably many closed sets.

Since there are Borel sets that are not $G_\delta$'s and $F_\sigma$'s, there are functions that are not pointwise limits of continuous functions.

As for the limits of integrals, see the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: For example if $f$ is the characteristic function of a subset of $K$ that is not $G_{\delta}$ nor $F_{\sigma}$.